# Revert setting the keyboard layout

Tags: command-line, keyboard-layout

I'm running a raspberry pi 3.0 on rasbian jessie lite and using a flat mac keyboard with the number pad on the right side. I do not have a GUI interface.

I went to change my keyboard layout because it was not correct (I couldn't use `|`). To do this, i installed console-common which let me select my layout from a list.

`sudo apt-get install console-common`

I selected `mac / Unknown / US american / Standard / Standard`. I think I should've chosen extended, but I'm still unsure about this part.

This was the incorrect layout and my keyboard is completely bonked. It seems like every key is mapped randomly. Does anyone have a suggestion of how i can revert this, other than manually writing out my new mapping, which is my last resort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To reconfigure the keyboard in Debian, run (as `root`, or using `sudo`):

```
dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

Link to official Debian documentation [here](https://wiki.debian.org/Keyboard).

If your keys are "random" (I have been there, not fun!), try to find the characters needed to execute the command above.

Comment: Thanks! I'm making some progress on the front. So far I got `j = enter`, `, = backspace`, `m = \``. I really just need to find up because this was my last command

Comment: welp i gave up and just wiped raspbian  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to another computer you can `ssh` to your Pi and reset the keyboard that way.

I cannot give you a recommended keyboard layout for a direct console connection because that varies from keyboard to keyboard and I don't have a Mac keyboard to test against.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with an alternate solution to my problem. Ultimately, my issue was the keyboard was registered as `gb` (great britain) instead of `us`.

To fix this, I had the prerequisites of `keyboard-configuration` and `console-setup` installed (not sure if the latter is actually necessary) and changed the file `/etc/default/keyboard`. A quick script to do this

```
sed -i 's/gb/us/g' /etc/default/keyboard
service keyboard-setup restart
```